# TeamCity intergration with YouTrack

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I would like to integrate TC and YT together. I've prepared YT so I can attach changes manually (works well). But I would like to do this automatically. 
I've visited "Issue trackers connections" in TC and I've filled all columns. 
I think, the problem is in TC because I cannot test connection. TC prints: "Error: No route to host"

When I look at a build and click on a issue browser opens new panel where is YT issue, so the url address looks fine. But there are no linked builds in TeamCity Changes.

What can be wrong? Some user roles? Or server port? Or my expectations about the functionality is wrong?

Comment: JetBrains support is probably a better location for this. StackOverflow is best suited to questions around specific bits of code that can be included in the question.

Comment: You are right. I think stackoverflow has bigger community so perhaps someone give me answer quicklier :). I'm going to post this question on jetbrains support :)

Comment: Few hours after detection of this problem YouTrack send me email about fixed ussues in build XY. The question is not answered but problem is fixed. (auto-rapaired software maybe).

Answer (score 1):

In order to see changes in YouTrack you need to configure YouTrack integration with TeamCity. TeamCity integration with YouTrack allows to open YouTrack issues and adds "Issue Log" tabs in TeamCity.

The reason why "Test connection" might not work is that the test is done from the TeamCity server machine to YouTrack. This is necessary for displaying issue details on hovering the issue ID and on Issue Log pages.